# "After all" usage

Tags: phrase-usage

When to use "After all" ? In what context? Could someone provide examples on this? 
In some contexts, i have seen it using as a 2 different words "after" and "all". I am really not clear on how to use this in our daily life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to use this phrase.

Firstly to begin a sentence, usually to express disappointment in an outcome after putting effort in to achieve a more agreeable result, e.g. "**After all** that, [and] I still didn't get a raise!".

Alternatively, at the end of a sentence, usually with a similar meaning but can also be used in a positive way, e.g. "And so, Billy got his ice cream **after all!**"

Sometimes you might find it in the middle of a sentence, e.g. "Because, **after all**, everything gets recycled eventually.", again with a similar meaning but not restricted to a specific set of events which have occurred, instead reflecting a more general tone.

Either way, to me it seems to signify a somewhat unexpected outcome has occurred after some, perhaps long-running, work or activity has taken place.

Comment: I'd also like to add that it could also be used in phrases like "After All is said and done", essentially meaning 'once a given set of events has completed, the following statement will likely be true...<statement>'.